# wordpress sorting using array merge by price in ascending order but price with 0 must be show last

Tags: wordpress

I'm using below code to filter the query on page and sort the post in ascending order by price. I'm getting desire output but my concern is , i want all price with 0 at last.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num','meta_key' => 'price','order' => 'ASC'));
query_posts( $args );
?>
```

please help me guys...Thanks in advance

full code here:

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Archive pages.
*
* Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
*
* @package progression
*/

get_header('cars'); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'page', 'vehicle-title' ); ?>
<div class="width-container">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="page-title">
<h1 id="page-heading">
<?php if (is_tax('vehicle_type')) {
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$tax_term_breadcrumb_taxonomy_slug = $term->taxonomy;
echo '' . $term->name . '';
}
?>
</h1>
</div><!-- close #page-title -->

<div id="4-content-container" class="tax-vehicle-container">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[vehicle_searchform include="make,model"]') ?> 

    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num','meta_key' => 'price','order' => 'ASC'));
    query_posts( $args );
 ?>



<?php
/* Start the Loop */
$count = 1;
$count_2 = 1;
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if($count >= 5) { $count = 1; }
?>

<div class="grid4column-progression <?php if($count == 4): echo ' lastcolumn-progression'; endif; ?>">
<?php
get_template_part( 'content', 'vehicle');
?>

</div>
<?php if($count == 4): ?><div class="clearfix"></div><?php endif; ?>
<?php $count ++; $count_2++; endwhile; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php show_pagination_links( ); ?>

</div><!-- close #content-container -->

<?php else : ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'inventory' ); ?>

</div><!-- close #content-container -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar( 'vehicle' ); ?>
</div><!-- close .width-container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will be useful to someone.. i done this way

```
<?php
    /* ADDED by for sorting ASCENDING order but call for price(ie price with 0) last */
    function my_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby =  "   case when CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED) = '0' then 1 else 0 end ,CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED)   ";
        return  $orderby;
    }
    add_filter('posts_orderby','my_sort_custom',10,2);
    global $wp_query;
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array('meta_key' => 'price'));
    query_posts( $args );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a small number of posts, the quick and dirty thing to do would be to traverse the loop twice, suppressing zeros on the first pass and suppressing everything except zeros on the second pass:

```
for ($i=0, $i++, $i<=1) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   $show_non_zeros = ($i === 0) && ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true) > 0); 
   $show_zero_price = ($i === 1) && ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true) == 0); 
   if ($show_non_zeros || $show_zero_price) {
      //write output
   }
   end while;
end for;
```

If you're looking for a faster / more elegant solution, you can [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) `$posts` between your call to `query_posts` and the loop.

Comment: Hi cpilko thanks for answer but im not able to implement it I'm new to wordpress...can you explain me how to use unsort. i will edit and post whole page code for better idea